# Problema con la biblioteca numpy en Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Se trata de un ejercício de práctica en el cual al arreglo de matriz (0 a 9) debo
invertir el signo de los valores entre (5 a 7), de modo que se imprima luego la
matriz completa ya con los elementos modificados.

```
import numpy as np

b = np.arange (10)
print (b)
print()
b = np.arange [(b >=5) & (b <=7)] * b =-1
print (b)
```

El resultado debería mostrarse :

```
([0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , -5 , -6 , -7 , 8 , 9])
```

Y el error es :

```
b = np.arange [(b >=5) & (b <=7)] * b =-1
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assing to operator
```

Ya miré la documentación de numpy y aún no resuelvo qué sintaxis es la correcta.

Answer (score 2):

Un ciclo `for` que solo altere el rango de elementos deseado (en este caso el elemento 5 al 7)

```
b = np.arange(10)
for i in b[5:8]:
    b[i] = b[i]*-1
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[ 0  1  2  3  4 -5 -6 -7  8  9]
```

Comment: gracias! , ésta sintáxis funcionó. saludos!

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

b = np.arange(10)
print(b)
print()
for i in b[5:8]:
    b[i] *= -1
print(b)
```

Tenías errores de sintaxis: faltaban los paréntesis de la función `np.arange()` y estabas haciendo una asignación donde no corresponde.

El resultado es:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

[ 0  1  2  3  4 -5 -6 -7  8  9]
```

Comment: gracias por la corrección pero ahora en ésa misma línea me muestra SyntaxisError : expression cannot contain assignment , perhaps you meant "=="?